# Two different locations for Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I had a 3-year old installation of Homebrew in /usr/local/Library/Homebrew. It didn't update properly, so I reinstalled it (without, unfortunately, uninstalling first). This time, Homebrew installed in /usr/local/Homebrew.

Not only are the folder locations different, but the subfolders also are different. Is the old installation deprecated and can I delete it? Or does the new installation depend on the old installation? This is under Mac OS Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure new installations of Homebrew are installed under `/usr/local/Homebrew/`, so I see no harm in deleting the old installation. I also noticed I have no `/usr/local/Library/` in my Sierra file structure.

To keep things tidy you might still be able to [delete the old installation using the script](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew) which has more uninstall options.

Answer (score 2):

FYI according to the [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#why-is-the-default-installation-prefix-opthomebrew-on-apple-silicon), the new installation folder on macOS on Apple Silicon is now `/opt/homebrew`.

> The prefix `/opt/homebrew` was chosen to allow installations in `/opt/homebrew` for Apple Silicon and `/usr/local` for Rosetta 2 to coexist and use bottles.

Comment: While relevant for newer installations and hardware, note the age of the question, and that the OP mentions Sierra, distinctly pre-AS.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths People searching for the topic via search engines may still end up here, having an answer which reflects the current situation provides value.

Comment: @nohillside Understood, hence why I attempted to qualify it. I wasn't clear enough in my statement vs my thought! Didn't want the takeaway that the old locations were invalid even on Intel.